# Would be possible to cover all the deserts with solar plates and satisfy the demand of electricity?

Tags: electricity, estimation, power, solar-cells

if we covered all the deserts with solar plates , would that be the solution to the energy crisis ?

i mean put a solar plates in ALL the deserts of the earth to harvest all solar power

Comment: This seems like more of an engineering and infrastructure question, rather than a physics question. But, from a physics perspective, if you know the worldwide demand for electricity, and you know the solar energy flux (about 1400 W/m^2 according to google), and you know the typical efficiency of a solar panel, and you know the total area of "all the deserts" then you can make an estimate. But this estimate does not cover distribution losses... this is why it is more of an engineering problem. Maybe try the engineering stack exchange.

Comment: And just to pile on more engineering problems, solar panels do not last forever; they can break, they can fail and need to be repaired; they can short-circuit and start on fire and potentially start the entire solar farm on fire, etc. There are tons of real-world problems that would have to be solved to "satisfy the demand of electricity."

Comment: Closed. As usual, questions about real world physics are unwelcome here. Come back when you have a question about a recherché whiteboard abstraction.

Comment: Hi Jose Perez. Welcome to Phys.SE. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope estimate?

Comment: An estimate 1600 ha --> 500 MW , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouarzazate_Solar_Power_Station

Answer (score 3):

> Would be possible to cover all the deserts with solar plates and satisfy the demand of electricity ?

Purely in terms of energy production, yes. In fact, just covering a fraction of the Sahara desert or the Australian outback with solar panels or [concentrated solar power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrated_solar_power) facilities could meet the world's energy requirements. And an organisation called [Desertec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desertec) aims to do just that.

However, there are significant practical obstacles to be overcome, such as energy distribution and large scale energy storage (after all, if it was easy it would have been done by now), as well as concerns about water usage, the impact on local ecosystems and climate change.

Here are links to a couple of articles that discuss these difficulties in more detail:

- https://www.projectsolaruk.com/blog/covering-the-sahara-with-solar-panels-may-not-be-as-viable-as-people-think
- https://regenpower.com/why-arent-we-using-the-deserts-for-solar-power/

Comment: and why do we always pick on deserts? All ecosystems are equal, except some are more equal than others.

Comment: @JEB - I think because many people equate ‘desert’ to flat, deserted, and useless to them. Reality is different of course.

Comment: There are also practical problems that will occur.  Sand storms will cover the solar panels in a fine layer of sand, requiring a lot of maintenance to keep the solar panels clean.  That maintenance will be expensive.  Thus, this is not the kind of problem solution where you just install the solar panels, walk away, and get "free" energy for 20-30 years.

Answer (score 2):

The area required to match the planet's consumption of electric energy through solar panels is remarkably small. I have $8m^2$ of solar panel in my roof, and get an average of $1800 kwh$ in a year. For $25500$ terawatts-hour, the Earth present consumption in a year, it is only necessary $14000 km^2$.

Of course, it should be scattered around the world, and not concentrated in some places like Saara or Atacama to avoid losses in transmission.

But there are 2 problems. First the cost around 8 trillions of dollars. Second, the energy peaks on the 4 hours around noon, and falls sharply out of that period.